# Setting global data in a data service to be accessible from all the components

Tags: angular

I am trying to save access token after login in a data service. 
I am setting the `accessToken` in `auth.service.ts` file after login and try to access this value in another file.

**data.service.ts**

```
_accessToken: string;

getAccessToken(){
    return this._accessToken;
}
setAccessToken(accessToken: string) {
    this._accessToken = accessToken;
}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
setSession(authResult) {
    this.dataService.setAccessToken(authResult);
    console.log(this.dataService.getAccessToken()); 
}
```

When I print `this.dataService.getAccessToken()` in `auth.service`, I get the correct access token.

Now I try to access it in a different component, I get `undefined`.

**order.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.dataService.getAccessToken());
}
```

The above results in `undefined`.

I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Is your `data.service` provided in the app module? If so it should be a single instance shared across the app, if it's provided at component level, it'll be a new instance per component and you'd see the behaviour you're describing.

Comment: Yes I have already added the entry in providers array of app.module.ts, still same issue

Comment: are you creating new instances of the service at the component level or using constructor injection?

Answer (score 1):

Your service decorators must have the `providedIn: 'root'` to be accessible.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class YourService {
  // Your service logic goes here
}
```

Comment: While that should work, it's not required.providedIn: root is just a shorthand for actually providing it in the app module.